# @Valid vs @Validated in Spring Boot Rest API @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am coming from a .NET background in developing REST APIs. Now working on java REST project using spring boot.

First my validation at the controller @RequestBody just stop working. While trying to fix it, I saw different ways to implement. So what would be the correct way to annotate the @RequestBody?

```
@Validated @RequestBody
```

or

```
@Valid @RequestBody
```

Answer (score 8):

There are generally no huge difference between them two, `@Valid` is from JSR-303 standand, `@Validated` is spring standard. according to spring document:

> Spring provides a Validator interface that can be used for validation in all layers of an application. In Spring MVC you can configure it for use as a global Validator instance, to be used whenever an @Valid or @Validated controller method argument is encountered, and/or as a local Validator within a controller through an @InitBinder method. Global and local validator instances can be combined to provide composite validation.

Reference:  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-validation

However there are differences, one of them is for example, if you need use `group` in your validation annotation, you need to use `@Validated`, it is not supported with `@Valid`.

Answer (score 0):

@Valid is in the JSR-Specification and @Validated is from spring framework.

When your program should be compatible to EJB/JSR Standard use @Valid otherwise you can use both.

Comment: consider adding documentation links